# How to order grouped data in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I am trying to get data that is grouped by `:user_id` for bar charts.

```
@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed: true).group(:user_id)
```

[image]
I want to organize it in descending order.

Howe can I do it?
In addition to it, is there a chance to rename the y-axis values?
Thanks in advance

I have tried to work with the following with different variables instead of ... , but it did not work:

```
@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed: true).group(:user_id).order("count(...) DESC")
```

UPDATE:
My query had been ordered. The problem is that Chartkick orders values for axis. Is there a chance to make axis unordered?

Chart code:

```
<%= bar_chart @completed_tasks.count%>
```

Comment: "did not work" is not helpful. Did you get an error? Did it return an ActiveRecord_Relation but no results? If you add `.first` to the end of your query it should show you any SQL errors.

Comment: Also can you show an example of the format your data is being returned from your query?

Comment: Renaming would depend on what your final query looks like and your data returned.

Comment: I tried this ```@completed_tasks = Task.where(completed: true).group(:user_id).first`` and got this error:  ```PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "tasks.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function . In Rails console I am trying to call the query without ```.first```, but it writes that ```(Object doesn't support #inspect)```

Comment: So is the chart actually working? Or is that just and example of what you want?

Comment: The chart is working with this code ```Task.where(completed: true).group(:user_id)```. I wonder how I can order it, I appended ```order("count(user_id) DESC") ``` and got no changes

Comment: Because you are on Rails 7 and the comment I made below about that being ignored in rails 7. You need to do something like `order("count( ? ) DESC", "user_id")`

Comment: Now it is not ignored and i am closer to the answer, the only thing to improve is this: ```Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "count( ? ) DESC".This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().``` I could not figure out how to add Arel.sql in my line. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I updated my question. Please, have a look

Comment: Please show the actual CHART code. It is very frustrating to people trying to help you when you don't add the simplest info. You need to show the ENTIRE flow, the query to get the data and the ChartKick method from your view. Also your chart is hard to understand. You have the Y axis sorted but what are you trying to show? It seems like you would want the bars running vertical. It looks like your user_id's are the Y axis? How about making a fake chart the the labels you WANT showing how perfect data would look??

Comment: And "rename the y-axis values". Rename to what? Do you want the user name instead of the ID?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the chart code, though it is short. I will update my question rn. Yes, I want to see user nicknames instead of ID

Answer (score 0):

I managed to perform this task by raw sql, but honestly, I tried serveral ways by using Rails Active record ORM. Hope my code could help a little bit:

```
sql = "Select count(id) as count_all, user_id from Tasks group_by user_id count_all desc"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) 
records_array.values
```

You will receive an array like: `[[10, 2], [9,3], ...]` in which `2,3` will be user_id, and `10,9` will be the number of records having correponding user_id.

Comment: For some reason, I get a syntax error: ```PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user_id" LINE 1: ...unt(id) as count_all, user_id from Task group_by user_id co... ^```

Comment: hi @Liuba, I copied it wrongly, could you try again with: 
`Select count(id) as count_all, user_id from Tasks group by user_id order by count_all desc`

`group_by` => `group by`.

Comment: Are you using Rails 7?

Comment: I updated my question. Please, have a look